# Javascript Regex Not Returning Correct Result

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is the code below. Basically, it returns true when whitespace is passed in the check?

```
var chars = [];
room.forEach(x => {
  if (/[a-z]/.test(x)) {
    chars.push(x);
    console.log(x);
  }
});
return chars;
```

Comment: what is the expected behavior?

Comment: Did you mean to match a string that only consists of lowercase letters? Use `/^[a-z]+$/`. Any ASCII letters: `/^[a-z]+$/i`.

Comment: Here is a repl of this test i have setup.  https://repl.it/MRgV/0

Comment: @CharlieE does the room variable always contain a two dimension array?

Comment: I want to say it will.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are only testing for the existence of any lowercase character anywhere in the string. You need to make sure to check that is only one lowercase character from start (^) to end ($).

```
  var chars = [];
  room.forEach(x => {
    if (/[^a-z$]/.test(x)) {
      chars.push(x);
      console.log(x);
    }
  });
  return chars;
```

Comment: This would be an example of what would be passed through this forEach.

Comment: var room=[
    ["a"," "," "," "," "],
    [" "," ","b"," "," "],
    [" "," "," "," "," "],
    [" ","c"," "," "," "],
    [" "," "," "," "," "]
    ];

Comment: The x, in this case, is an array!